# find documents with matching fields across collection and add new field from matched document

Tags: mongodb

I have collections `cars`, `registrations`, `car_specs`

I need to create two new collections

1. `cars_registrations` - this adds the `RegNo` from `registrations` to `cars` for documents with same `StreetNo` and `HouseNo`, discarding documents with no match.
2. `cars_registrations_spec` - this adds `CarSpec` from `car_specs` to `cars_registrations` collection for for documents with same `StreetNo` and `HouseNo`.

What is the most efficient way doing this from console - I have 500K documents in the `cars` collection and 50K documents in the `registrations` collection.

**cars:**

```
[
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "12",  "Car": "camry" },
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "13",  "Car": "camry" },
        { "StreetNo": 323, "HouseNo": "12",  "Car": "accord" },
        { "StreetNo": 324, "HouseNo": "15",  "Car": "Sunny" }
    ]
```

**registrations:**

```
[
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "12",  "RegNo": "1122" },
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "13",  "RegNo": "1123" },
        { "StreetNo": 323, "HouseNo": "12",  "RegNo": "1124" },
    ]
```

**cars_registrations**

```
[
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "12",  "Car": "camry",  "RegNo": "1122"  },
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "13",  "Car": "camry",  "RegNo": "1123" },
        { "StreetNo": 323, "HouseNo": "12",  "Car": "accord",  "RegNo": "1124" }
    ]
```

**car_specs**

```
[
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "12",  "CarSpec": {"cyl": "4", "gear": "5"} },
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "13",  "CarSpec": {"cyl": "4", "gear": "5"} },
        { "StreetNo": 323, "HouseNo": "12",  "CarSpec": {"cyl": "6", "gear": "7"} }
    ]
```

**cars_registrations_spec**

```
[
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "12",  "Car": "camry",  "RegNo": "1122",  "CarSpec": {"cyl": "4", "gear": "5"} },
        { "StreetNo": 321, "HouseNo": "13",  "Car": "camry",  "RegNo": "1123",  "CarSpec": {"cyl": "4", "gear": "5"} },
        { "StreetNo": 323, "HouseNo": "12",  "Car": "accord", "RegNo": "1124", "CarSpec": {"cyl": "6", "gear": "7"} }
    ]
```

Below is one approach attempted. However, this takes forever to complete with the number of documents in the collection - what is the right `mongodb way` of doing this ?

**for cars_registrations**

```
var results = db.registrations.find({}, {_id: 0}).toArray();
for( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var car = db.car.findOne({$and: [{StreetNo: results[i]["StreetNo"]},
    {HouseNo: results[i]["HouseNo"]}] }, {_id: 0});
    if(car && results[i]["RegNo"]) {
        car["RegNo"] = results[i]["RegNo"]
        db.cars_registrations.insertOne(car);
    }
}
```

The issue I have with this is that it takes a long time - many many hours - My guess is that the `findOne` with `$and` is taking a lot of time - for me it takes many hours to get this done on a cars collection with 500K docs and registrations collection with 50K docs. Is this usual to take so much time ?

Comment: You're going to want to use the aggregation framework.